# Google Cloud regionInstanceGroups seem to be unusable, API doesn't have insert method

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Trying to see if someone can shed light on this for me. I stumbled upon [this API object in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionInstanceGroups) when trying to find something that would allow me to use a region-wide unmanaged instance group. This API object suggests that it's possible, but there's no API insert method, only get and list.

Can someone help me understand what this API object does, it's purpose and how to use it?

Comment: I deleted my answer. Google does not make all APIs available. For some APIs you need to have your project whitelisted to enable the feature/API. If you have a Google account manager, discuss this with them.

Comment: Thanks John, appreciate the responses

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be this [method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroups/addInstances)

From the [overview](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroups) page the instranceGroups category represents an unmanaged Instance Group resource

As suggested by John not all API calls are available if you are looking for any feature not available in GCP you can [open a Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with Google for evaluation

Comment: instanceGroups are zonal. I was interested in the api object mentioned specifically because it seemed to be the one for regional instance groups. I'm assuming it's just not GA yet to create and manage one based on the responses. Thanks.